# Weird object members are shown when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, .net-4.0, console

When inspecting an instance of a class (normal class, composed of strings, ints and booleans) using the VS2010 Ultimate SP1 debugger, I can see all of the props that I've defined in the class, but I've also noticed a couple of things that shouldn't be there.

They appear with a blue box symbol and a '?'.

What are they?

Is my class sick? Are they class-tumors? (ha ha)... or even worst.

Has my VS2010 cancer?

Here's a screen shot, so you can see what I mean.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I was tempted to write "yes your visual studio does have cancer!" - as I've never seen this error before. It happens everytime you debug, but only on this specific class?

Comment: Me too its the first time I notice this behavior. Happens to all objects. One thing that I've noticed is that it *ONLY* happens when you have more props that VS can see and you scroll down using the mouse wheel... then I see this.

Comment: It is a quirk of the debugger and strikes somewhat randomly.  Some might call it a bug, that's probably the accurate description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my VS2010 has some weird **degenerative disorder**. I hope it's only mine.

I found out how that those '?' are the members of the class that VS2010 can't normally show in the vertical space that it creates when you inspect an object.

**1)** You inspect an object. VS shows you the (x) first members and a down arrow.

[image: First inspector screen]

**2)** You mouse-over the down arrow, VS will show you what's missing.

[image: Normal expansion of the members]

**3)** If you repeat the exercise (load the inspector again) but use the mouse wheel instead of using the mouse-over in the down arrow, you'll see the weird things.

[image: Alzheimer VS2010]